# replace unknown characters between two known characters in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following:

```
$string="rgb(Unknown characters) some text rgb(Unknown characters)";
```

I want to replace the the text `Unknown characters` with some replacement. I have tried this:

```
echo str_replace("Unknown characters","some replace characters",$string);
```

This works for an exact text match but I don't know what is inside the parentheses.

I would like the output to be

```
rgb(some replace characters) some text rgb(some replace characters)
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is `$echo` ???!!! It must be `echo` I think issue is `$echo` only, your code is working https://3v4l.org/NHdWU

Comment: rgb(some replace characters) some text rgb(some replace characters)
 final Output

Comment: Start here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: i dont know Unkown characters in string

Comment: Could you please confirm in your question that you need to replace whatever text is inside the brackets ()

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a regex:

```
$string="rgb(Unkown characters) some text rgb(Unkown characters)";
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","(some replace characters)",$string);
```

**Output:**

```
rgb(some replace characters) some text rgb(some replace characters)
```

**Regex:**

```
/         : regex delimiter
  \(      : open parenthesis
  [^)]+   : 1 or more any character that is not close parenthesis
  \)      : close parenthesis
/         : regex delimiter
```

Comment: A bit more explanation of the regex used would be useful as the OP has clearly not used them before